# Similar fonts to Porcha 911 which is free for commercial use?

Tags: fonts, typography, resource-recommendations, royalty-free

Does anyone know a good alternative to Porcha 911 font which is free for commercial use?

See image and link below.

[image]

https://www.dafont.com/911porscha.font?text=Detailing

Comment: If you are looking for free fonts to use commercially, your best bet is probably to avoid sites like dafont. Instead have a look at google fonts, or fontlibrary. These have a good selection of fonts with free/open source /SIL open font licences, etc, which can be used commercially.  Obviously you might not find something exactly the same, but perhaps a similar look - wide/flat square type sans-serif fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exact matches, but I found these. **All free for commercial use**.

From most to least similar:

- https://justinpenner.gumroad.com/l/36fonts16
- https://befonts.com/otr-type-font.html
- http://mickaelemile.fr/ (look for grind grotesque, 3rd option)
- https://willemdimas.gumroad.com/l/genesysfont

Hope any of them fits your needs!

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find any similar *free* fonts, but if you can spend a few bucks and tolerate some differences, see:

- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/john-moore/spacelab/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hansco/ateros/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/korataki/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/grype/aspire-smallcaps/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/gleb-guralnyk/lost-in-space/